# Why does there seem to be a delay in firing my click() event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've got a grid with an Accept/Decline radio button set in each row.

When a radio button is clicked, an ajax call is made to check if any of the rows need to be disabled, and the grid is refreshed.

I have some code that should immediately disable all the radio buttons when one is clicked so the user cannot choose additional options until the refresh occurs:

```
$('input').click(function(){
    $('input').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

but even this simple code has a lag of ~500ms on the page before it takes affect. Other times it happens almost immediately.

I don't have much control over the overall HTML/other scripts on the page that may be running or causing this to slow down if that is the culprit. Is there anything I can do just in terms of setting up the event listeners to disable the radio buttons more quickly, or prevent them from being clicked?

Comment: please use jsfiddle.net to make a sample showing the issue. it's likely due to some other code

Comment: Does your page have a **ton** of HTML? How many radio buttons are being disabled?

Comment: It could be because your HTML has got lot of input tags.. Their may be some delay As on click of any input tag it will fire and will disable all other input.

Comment: Could be that the AJAX request being made when clicking radio buttons is a synchronous request and triggered in an event handler that's attached to the radio buttons before yours is.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

After rereading your question:

> When a radio button is clicked, an ajax call is made to check if any
>   of the rows need to be disabled, and the grid is refreshed.

It sounds like that could be the culprit. Is there any chance that the ajax request is a `synchronous` request (`async: false`) and triggered before your click handler? There could be a click handler attached to these radio buttons before you've bound yours. That first handler would get executed first, and a synchronous request would block all other code from executing until it completes... the AJAX request *may* be taking ~500ms.

That could also explain this odd behavior:

> but even this simple code has a lag of ~500ms on the page before it
>   takes affect. Other times it happens almost immediately.

**If this is what's going on**, you want to disable the radio buttons from inside of that handler before the AJAX request is made.

---

Your code doesn't look like it should take ~500ms to run -- even if there are an insane number of radio buttons on the page. 2 ways that you could write the same code more efficiently are:

- **Cache radio buttons**: Your code searches the DOM for all of the radio buttons when one is clicked. You could speed up the execution of the click handler by searching for the radio buttons ahead of time.
- **Use 1 event handler**: Use 1 delegated event handler on the body, rather than setting up a click handler on every single input. It could be that there are a ton of radio buttons and binding the click handler on every one of them may be taking longer than expected... but it would have to take a *lot* of inputs for this to be the culprit.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // cache radiobuttons
  var all_radiobuttons = $('input[type="radio"]');

  // This one handler on the body will handle clicks events for all input[type="radio"].
  $(document.body).on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function() {
      all_radiobuttons.prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Test <input type="radio"></input></label>
<label>Test <input type="radio"></input></label>
```